# Cannot set "User Notification Listener" capablity in visual studio for UWP app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, notifications, uwp, toast

I'm trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener) guide on setting up a notification listener in a unified windows platform (UWP) application. I've got the example code running up until `listener.RequestAccessAsync` is called, but it keeps returning `UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Denied` without asking me to allow the application to access that information (it also never asked me before and I cannot find the app in `ms-settings:privacy-notifications`.

I've tried to set the capabilities of the app to allow "User Notification Listener" like it says in the first paragraph of the above mentioned page, but that does not appear in the list of available capability settings in my `Package.appxmanifest`. The target and minimal supported version for the project solution is 16299.

Is there a way to make this work or has this broken since this feature was added in windows build 14393?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to manually add this capability to the manifest. Right-click on the *Package.appxmanifest* in the *Solution Explorer* and select *View Code*. Make the following changes to the file:

```
<Package ...
     xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3"  
     IgnorableNamespaces="... uap3">
     ...
     <Capabilities>
          ...
          <uap3:Capability Name="userNotificationListener"/>  
     </Capabilities>
</Package>
```