# How to detect windows action center events programatically?

Tags: .net, winapi, .net-core, pywin32, event-log

I posted before asking how to do this in Python, but I'm not sure python even has an API for this.

I'm trying to detect Windows Action Center events. This Python code will detect some events, but is unreliable and can't determine exactly the type of event:

```
h = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(None, "System")
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
for record in win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(h, flags, 0):
    if record.EventID == 10016:
        print("it's a google calendar event (or something similar)!")
```

However, other events, such as Google chat events from Chrome, don't seem to cause a Windows system event, even though they show up in Action Center.

Is there any way to programmatically detect Windows Action Center events, in either C/C++ or Python (preferably), or even a .NET language like C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can use a listener and [listen for Toast notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener). But I'm realizing I actually don't want the dependency on .NET so I might try to figure out how to do it in C/C++ or Python.

EDIT: After I wrote a draft in C# I [converted it to Python here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788131/accessing-google-calendar-events-using-notificationlistener-api-in-python-window), but not all events are showing up yet.

Comment: There is no dependency on .NET or the CLR. The Windows Runtime is a native platform. A decade into the [Windows Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) and Microsoft still haven't successfully communicated this.

Comment: Thanks, this is great...so my preference is to use Python, but now I'm running into "UserNotificationListener is not activatable". Any ideas how to solve this in Python with VSCode? In Visual Studio this would be solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485447/cannot-set-user-notification-listener-capablity-in-visual-studio-for-uwp-app

Comment: Or even a sample C# winrt application? I can't even find any examples....the windows ecosystem is terrible...I tried created a C# WPF application and adding Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT as a Nuget dependency but it doesn't even install correctly. In other words, any C# app I make in Visual Studio doesn't have "using Windows.UI" as a valid package...even after installing the Nuget dependency. I don't do much Windows development but shouldn't I just be adding a dependency line to a config file and calling it a day......what is this?!

Comment: I did find this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy5VB-2kF6I but his template has CsWinRT using statements and mine doesn't

Comment: tried using https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/tree/master/src/Samples/WinUIDesktopSample but i get "type or name "controls" does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.UI.XAML"

Comment: Got it working. Used these in addition to the link from the answer https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/tree/master/src/Samples/BgTaskComponent and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095140/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-a-windows-10-notification-in-a-uwp-c